# Information propagation of tension loss in string

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, string

Suppose I have a horizontal taut string between two points. The string will have some tension $T$.

If one end of the string is suddenly cut, how will this information of tension loss travel to the other end of the string? Can we express the tension at some position $x$ in the string after the cut as a function of time?

Comment: You could model the string as an infinite series of connected identical elemental springs, and write coupled equations of motion for each element. Or are you asking for someone to do the calculation for you? Unlike a real string you will probably have to assume the string is confined to a straight line.

Comment: No, I'll be interested in doing the calculation myself. I was looking if there is a way without assuming the string as a straight line or if there is an answer to this at an atomic level. Thanks